# Disabling new editor in our Teams site

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams, markdown, stacks-editor

How can I get rid of this new editor? Is that a paid feature? An editor that can't handle basic rearrangement of text is just in the way, and there are so many ways it can go wrong. Markdown + preview was a lot less stressful.

Just as one example, paste this Markdown content into the editor and then switch back to the "new" editor. How would you move the quote above the code block? How would you even add normal text above the code block? I watched one of our new devs try to do this, and it just kept getting worse and worse as he tried to fix it.

```
    some code

> block quote
```

I'm also starting to suspect it's causing issues with formatting in comments, possibly depending on whether you left the last editor you used in Markdown mode or not.

Comment: I've never been able to make this editor work, either. I would love a way to turn it off. It makes it impossible for me to contribute any posts to any of the Teams that I am a member of. There have even been threats that this same editor will be rolled out to the main site, and that would be a *very* bad day, indeed. I wouldn't be able to post anything at all. Another problem you didn't even mention is that switching back and forth between Markdown and Formatted modes actually *changes* the Markdown that you've previously typed into the editor. Any type of complex formatting is impossible.

Comment: Doesn't the profile preference affect teams?

Comment: No, it does not, @Zoe, because I have certainly not opted in to the new editor (and don't see it on the main site or Meta), but I do see it on all of my Teams. But you've a nugget of a great idea hidden in there!

Answer (score -20):

The "new" editor is the only editor available to Teams. There is no option to disable it.

Comment: Slightly amazed that a terse "your stuck with it" answer from upper management doesn't even address the pain point behind the request with even a "we're working on the bugs" acknowledgment. Could lead some to think the new tooling is not going well after the proverbial 6-8 months

Comment: It's not too late to turn back. I've seen many, many attempts at WYSIWYG editors since the mid-90s, and few if any successes.