# Possible bug with Home key in editor

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not totally sure if this is a bug, or 'as designed', but I noticed tonight, while I was posting a question, that if I push the <kbd>Home</kbd> key while on an empty line, in the editor, my cursor gets moved to the start of the first line in the editor.

It's not so bad if you're on a fairly small question, but if you've typed a fair bit, and inadvertently press <kbd>Home</kbd>, you're whisked off to the top of the page!

The same isn't true of <kbd>End</kbd> on an empty line - this takes you to the start of the next line!

Browser, as requested, is Chrome Version 91.0.4472.164 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I thought that was the point of the home button.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to take you to the start of the line, normally.  Usually Ctrl + Home will take you to the top (as per most editors).  I've just used it here to correct a mistake in this comment! ;o)

Comment: Oh.. I see. Yes, that is correct. My mistake. I just tried it and it "home" takes me to the beginning of the line while end just takes me to the end. Could it be your browser? ..oops.. another mistake. I didn't try an empty line. I think it's fair to say I can reproduce this on Windows 10 with Opera .

Comment: Just using Chrome....

Comment: Which site is this on and which editor are you using? The normal one or the new [alpha editor](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/289905)? If the latter, there’s a related [bug report](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/360251/289905). No repro in the normal editor in Firefox Nightly 92.0a1.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - This was with SO, so whichever it uses (not sure, if I'm honest!).

Comment: @Paul The old one, then.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - If it's being replaced, do you want me to delete this post?

Comment: @Paul The new editor has some issues, see [Disabling new editor in our Teams site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409045/disabling-new-editor-in-our-teams-site).. there are people that hope it will never come to Stack.

Comment: @Paul Definitely don't delete; it's a genuine bug, and a post about it should stay– this is the right place for those :)

Comment: @zcoop98 - Yep - no worries!

Comment: Note: This is reproducible in the new editor too. Both in Markdown and RT modes.

Comment: No repro in FF90

Comment: Actually, I think this has to do with the browser and it's not specific to SE's editor(s). On Chrome, I managed to reproduce on several other websites like [Gmail](https://mail.google.com) and https://translage.google.com.

Comment: @Scratte You just tripped a bad memory. Did you check to see what happens with the [Oprah browser](https://www.theregister.com/2003/02/06/msn_deliberately_breaks_operas_browser/)?

Comment: @user4581301 This didn't go away. I have issue with some sites like Microsoft's devblogs. But I'll just use a different browser if I feel the need to read one of those, which happen about once a year ;)

Comment: No repo in Firefox 89 and Chrome 91