# I find the new editor (as used on Teams and in the Ask Wizard) unusable—what workarounds are available to reduce my need to use it while posting?

Tags: discussion, stacks-editor

I have tried the new editor. I don't like it.

The new editor is served up in multiple places:

- On all Stack Overflow for Teams sites (including those that are specifically relevant to the public platform, such as the Moderator Team and [the Team for the Staging Ground beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421718)), with [no way to disable it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409045).
- [It is also used in the Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417091/disable-the-stacks-editor-in-the-new-ask-wizard) on Stack Overflow, again, with no option to disable it.
- It is also available as [an option on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033).

The truth is, "I don't like it" is a serious understatement. Lately, I really find it *utterly maddening*. I wish I could go back to the old editor, but, as far as I know, I cannot. All requests to offer the old editor as an alternative have been marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

My normal workflow (like most of you, I suspect) is to draft directly in the editor on the target site. Mostly, I do this because I find the "Related" questions suggestions helpful. Sometimes, I keep it "as draft" (without publishing it); sometimes I publish, then delete to prevent losing the "draft", and undelete later.

I'm at my wit's end, and I'm looking for alternatives/workarounds. I really need to find something before the next phase of the Staging Ground project starts.

So, **what are my options for alternative editors and/or ways to avoid using the new editor in places where it is forced upon me**?

I would like to use something that will not be too complicated to convert into the Markdown flavor used by Stack Overflow. (If it has a way to automatically pull the title of the linked questions, so much the better.)

What do you suggest as a workflow for posting in Teams **in order to avoid having to use the new editor** as much as possible?

There was [a question asked about this on Software Recs.SE back in 2014](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14342), where it was suggested to use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/). However, I don't know if it's able to post directly to SO. I'm also wondering if it might be better to use a basic word processor like Google Docs and then use something to convert it to Markdown.

Comment: If you really don't the editor (like many of us) then you could write the post in something else; I frequently write stuff in VSCode, for example.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I have tried to say StackEdit, the webapp / Chrome Extension.

Comment: What exactly is so frustrating about it? Eventually... it will be launched whether we like it or not, it'd be more productive to address it's issues than to pretend it doesn't exist until it's the only option.

Comment: @KevinB I'm afraid that talking about that ("What exactly is so frustrating about it?" I saw your comment before it was edited)  might derail the comments here. Please extend your question to help keep the conversation focused (I don't think that this is a proper place to freely talk about frustration). Another option might be to point me/others to a proper place to talk about Stack Editor frustration, preferible with clear rules and "safe" policy

Comment: @KevinB I spare more time writing posts in sites were the Stack Editor is not available than on those were it is available. While my consious control system might "adjust" quickly, my unconsious control system doesn't, causing that the rate of errors be enourmously bigger than usual and worst, when editing new appears problems like code, indentation, links, etc. not displayed as before the edit due to the insertion of escape characters... there are already [meta-tag:bugs] about that, one of them is mine.