# Are questions about Stack Overflow for Teams on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow? Where can I get support?

Tags: support, faq, scope, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have a:

- bug report
- feature request
- support question
- pre-sales inquiry
- some other type of question

…related to the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product. Since this is a product of Stack Overflow (the company) and part of the larger Stack Overflow ecosystem, can I ask my question here on Meta Stack Overflow?

What sorts of questions related to Stack Overflow for Teams belong here on Meta Stack Overflow, if any?

Where do I go in order to ask questions about and/or get support for Stack Overflow for Teams, if not here?

---

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

Answer (score 24):

### Are questions about the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product *on-topic* for this site (Meta Stack Overflow)?

In general, **no**. Questions, bug reports, feature requests, and other lines of inquiry specifically related to the Stack Overflow for Teams product are off-topic here on Meta Stack Overflow.

The **one exception** to this blanket policy of Teams-related questions being off-topic for Meta Stack Overflow is *general* questions about the relationship between the Stack Overflow for Teams product and the public site. Because such questions are at least partially about the public site, for which Meta Stack Overflow is the appropriate support venue, they are on-topic here.

### So, *where* can I ask questions about the Stack Overflow for Teams product, if not here on Meta Stack Overflow?

First, check the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.help/en/) and [support documentation](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/22000109000) to see if your question has already been answered.

If you cannot find your answer(s) there, go to [the dedicated **web portal**](https://s.tk/support) and open a support ticket. This portal provides priority support for *all tiers* of the Stack Overflow for Teams product, including Free, Basic, Business, and Enterprise. There, you will find categories allowing you to report bugs, request features, get customer or technical support with an issue, and even an "Other" category for requests that don't fit into any other category. The support tickets raised via this portal go directly into Freshdesk, which is Stack Overflow's internal ticketing system. From there, they are assigned to dedicated staff members who provide priority support for the Teams product.

Alternatively, in lieu of submitting a ticket via the web portal, you can send an email to `support@stackoverflow.com`. The Business and Enterprise plans include on-call weekend and holiday support. The Enterprise plan also includes a dedicated Customer Success Manager (CSM), whom you can contact.

**Pre-sales inquiries for the Enterprise plan** can also fill out the contact form provided when clicking the "Talk to an expert" button on [the pricing page](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/#p-pricing-grid-enterprise).

Note that **"meta" discussions internal to a Team** (e.g., about the operations, mechanics, policies, and/or moderation of the Team) belong directly on that Team. As the administrator of a Team, you have nearly complete control over the content of your Team and how you want to administer it. For hosting "meta" discussions specifically about your Team, you might consider assigning a dedicated tag (e.g., [meta]) to all such questions on your Team (resulting in each Team also being its own meta, like the public [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/meta) Q&A site), or even creating an additional Team to fully separate the discussions.

### *Why* are questions about the Stack Overflow for Teams product off-topic for Meta Stack Overflow?

The [Stack Overflow moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) have arrived at this policy based on our own common sense and in consultation with Stack Overflow employees.

We recognize that this is a departure from previous precedent, where questions about Stack Overflow for Teams were allowed and even encouraged here on Meta Stack Overflow. However, circumstances have changed, including but not limited to [the complete separation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420980) of Teams from the public Stack Overflow by giving Teams its own, dedicated domain. These changing circumstances have prompted the original policy to be re-considered. Meta Stack Overflow is no longer considered the primary (or even a valid) support venue for the Teams product.

While both products are provided by the same company, Stack Overflow for Teams is a separate product from the public Stack Overflow platform. Therefore, these two products are not supported by the same site. (Meta Stack Overflow exists to support the public Stack Overflow site.)

The primary reason for this (i.e., the simple answer to the "why" question) is because that's what Stack Overflow employees have said they want. Specifically, staff wants all inquiries related to the Stack Overflow for Teams product to be raised as tickets in their dedicated support portal for that product.

This has been suggested by [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338) on multiple occasions (via [messages in private chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=62537773)). More recently, [Juice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141235/juice), the Director of Product Support at Stack Overflow, explicitly clarified the company's current policy by editing [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385134) originally posted by [Makyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) in response to [a formal inquiry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385124) as to the exact policy by [Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2370483/machavity).

Beyond the straightforward matter of what has been requested by staff, there are additional practical reasons why it does not make sense for Meta Stack Overflow to serve as a support venue for the Stack Overflow for Teams product. There are many aspects of Teams—including account information, and even what Team(s) a particular user belongs to—that are considered private details which cannot be disclosed on a public site like Meta Stack Overflow. Without the ability to make specific, contextual information available, a public report becomes impossible to generate and much less beneficial to other users who encounter the same problem on Teams (as they may not even be able to determine its relevance to their own situation). Even though the poster of the question may be comfortable revealing certain pieces of relevant information, anyone who would attempt to answer the question would likely need to know additional information above and beyond what is or can reasonably be made public.

### What should be *done* with questions about the Stack Overflow for Teams product that are posted on Meta Stack Overflow?

First, determine whether the question is about the *interaction* between Teams and the public site. These questions are explicitly on-topic because they are at least partially about the public site, even though most questions about Teams are off-topic here.

Once you've determined that the question is specifically about Teams, and is *not* about the relationship between Teams and the public site, then this means that the question is off-topic for Meta Stack Overflow and should be closed.

We have a dedicated, community-specific close reason for these types of questions on Meta Stack Overflow, which reads:

> **Closed.** This question is about the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product, which has a dedicated [support portal](https://s.tk/support). It is not accepting answers here.
>
> ---
>
> Meta Stack Overflow does not provide support for the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product. Instead, bug reports, feature requests, customer support, and other questions specific to Stack Overflow for Teams should be sent directly to staff via the [**support portal**](https://s.tk/support) or emailed to support@stackoverflow.com. For Enterprise plan pre-sales, you can ["Talk to an expert" from the pricing page](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/#p-pricing-grid-enterprise).

The author of the question will instead see this variant of the message:

> **Closed.** This question is about the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product, which has a dedicated [support portal](https://s.tk/support). It is not accepting answers here.
>
> ---
>
> A [**support portal**](https://s.tk/support) provides priority support from dedicated staff for questions about [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) (e.g., bug reports, feature requests, customer support, etc.). Alternatively, email support@stackoverflow.com. For Enterprise plan pre-sales inquiries, you can ["Talk to an expert" from the pricing page](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/#p-pricing-grid-enterprise). If your question is actually about the public site, please edit to clarify.

This variant has been optimized to put the link to the support portal at the beginning of the message. It also includes a fail-safe at the end: in the unlikely event that a question was misunderstood and mistakenly closed as being specific to Teams, the author is advised to edit their question in order to clarify that it was actually about the public site.

The following guidance is displayed to prospective close-voters considering the use of this close reason:

> **Specific to the Stack Overflow for Teams product**
> Use this close reason for questions specifically about the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams) product (e.g., bug reports, feature requests, customer support tickets, pre-sales inquiries, etc.). The asker will be advised that they should direct their inquiries to the [support portal](https://s.tk/support) instead. Do not use this close reason for *general* questions about the relationship between Stack Overflow for Teams and the public site, which may be asked on Meta Stack Overflow.

Note that this explicitly calls out the exception described above, that "*general* questions about the relationship between Stack Overflow for Teams and the public site … may be asked on Meta Stack Overflow". Such questions should *not* be closed because they are not *specifically* about Teams but are, rather, about the broader Stack Overflow ecosystem, which includes Teams.

If you see a question which has been mistakenly closed using this reason, you should vote to re-open it and/or flag it for moderator attention.

All things considered, moderators and staff alike feel that having a dedicated close reason that directs users to the appropriate place to get support is the most appropriate way to handle questions that are specifically about the Stack Overflow for Teams product.

### But what about the new *Stacks Editor* used by the Stack Overflow for Teams product?

The Stacks Editor used to compose/modify posts on Teams is terrible, buggy, difficult to use, and constantly defies expectations. Attempts to use it regularly result in lost data and a lower overall quality of posts.

Despite consistent, substantially negative feedback from the user-base, going back two-and-a-half years, that this new editor is riddled with bugs and frustrating to use (compared to the original one still used on public Stack Overflow), the company has chosen to largely ignore the complaints, deploy it to their Teams product (as well as forced its use in a variety of other situations where it has been empirically proven to harm the user experience and result in a lowered quality of content), and [declined to provide an option to opt out or disable it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409045).

Your only real avenues of recourse are:

- Submit bug reports and/or feature requests using one of the avenues described above;

  - *If the issue is not Teams-specific*, then bug reports and/or feature requests for the Stacks Editor may be posted either here on Meta Stack Overflow or on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), since this editor is used in certain places on Stack Overflow and use of a "beta" version is available as an opt-in option on both Meta sites.
- Vote with your feet/wallet (by choosing not to use Teams until the situation is rectified); or
- Get involved with the development on [the public GitHub repository](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor).

Comment: What is the best place to provide feedback on this decision?  Personally I find it really ironic and frustrating that I can't use the same knowledge/solution sharing model for StackOverflow for Teams problems/questions as I can for any other knowledge domain supported by StackExchange websites.  There are so many reasons I like the StackExchange model and very few of them hold true for the support portal.

Comment: @snydergd That's a good question; unfortunately, I don't have a good answer for you. I suppose you could start a discussion here on MSO or [Meta.SE], but for all the reasons described in this answer, I don't think the policy is likely to change. The main thing is that these are community-supported Q&A sites, and, for a variety of reasons, provide help for a closed-source, inaccessible product like Teams. The minor thing is that this is what the company wants. I agree it's frustrating, and I made similar arguments internally when we were formulating the policy, but it is what it is.