# Team building on SO for teams

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am currently exploring the new feature which allows teams to have a space on SO. I am wondering what is allowed when building a small team for a specific purpose. Is there any documented information on this (please share pointers)?

Is it acceptable, for instance, to publicly advertise a team on SO for potential joiners to notice and possibly join?
If so, are there any guidelines or rules to go about doing this? Does the notice have to be shared on meta? Or mainstream SO?

Or is it the case that I do need to have a team locally? Possibly onboard interested colleagues from the office to sign up directly. How does building a team on here work?

As read from [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423394/are-questions-about-stack-overflow-for-teams-on-topic-for-meta-stack-overflow-w)

> What should be done with questions about the Stack Overflow for Teams product that are posted on Meta Stack Overflow?
>
> First, determine whether the question is about the interaction between
> Teams and the public site. These questions are explicitly on-topic
> because they are at least partially about the public site, even though
> most questions about Teams are off-topic here.
>
> Once you've determined that the question is specifically about Teams,
> and is not about the relationship between Teams and the public site,
> then this means that the question is off-topic for Meta Stack Overflow
> and should be closed.
>
> We have a dedicated, community-specific close reason for these types
> of questions on Meta Stack Overflow, which reads:

It sounds like they can be considered under certain circumstances.

Comment: The paragraphs you quote would say that **this** question could be on-topic, not that the type of question you propose asking would be on-topic anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it acceptable for instance to publicly advertise a team on SO for potential joiners to notice and possibly join

No, it is **not acceptable** to advertise a team on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow. For the main site please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Any questions advertising a Stack Overflow team are off-topic, comments doing the same will be liable for deletion. For Meta see: [Are questions about Stack Overflow for Teams on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow? Where can I get support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423394/are-questions-about-stack-overflow-for-teams-on-topic-for-meta-stack-overflow-w)

You can try looking for interested people in various [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), note that some of these rooms might have rules of their own so please check before you decide to post.

Comment: I think it depends, can you take a look at the section on::  "What should be done with questions about the Stack Overflow for Teams product that are posted on Meta Stack Overflow?" it specifies the condition under which it can be considered off topic or not

Comment: @user23463397 the allowances given under that section don't include advertising an SO Team. It allows questions like this current one that you've asked which ask about the relationship between Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Teams.

Comment: For instance if I want to know how to tell  (advertise) the public site about a teams workspace, then I think this can be considered as a topic about the relationship between the public and Teams.

Comment: @user23463397 please don't try to stretch the rules, you've asked here whether advertising an SO team would be allowed and have received the answer that it won't be. If you ask the question you just suggested in your comment that would simply be closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @user23463397 And that would be **this** question. Which is why you are getting an answer, telling you that you cannot use either (meta or main) to advertise (teams or anything else for that matter).

Comment: @user23463397 - You cannot advertise your private Teams community on SE unless you were to pay SE to advertise your private Teams community. Don’t advertise your private Teams community on any SE. Your spam, yes it would be considered to be spam, would just get you suspended from SE.

Comment: you know to a large extent @SecurityHound I agree with most of the points made. But when I tagged it a discussion I was expecting ideas of what can be done if it can't come on SE, could there be an exchange for SO teams and similar brainstorming like that. I was banking on it being called bad and just bad. I was hoping some people might find a bright side to it and make suggestions ..  But certainly it looks unanimous up the comments  and post votes so...

Comment: @user23463397 - Saying something isn’t a good idea is participating in a discussion. Saying in no certain terms that spamming SE communities with offers to join your private Team community is not allowed is participating in the discussion.

Comment: @SecurityHound "spamming SE communities with offers to join your private Team community is not allowed" --- this is not what I want. My post was not asking for this either

Comment: im only saying everyone looks at the dark side and with no second thought of what could be a way out

Comment: @user23463397 - You were asking if you could promote your private Team community. I don't see a huge difference between unwanted promotion of a product and spamming the community with spam. This might be a harsh description of what you wanted to verify was allowed but in reality I rarely see self-promotion done properly.

Comment: as far as I know, spams are quite pushy and they come into your space (inbox, timeline), hard to overlook them etc.. That isn't what I imagined when I made the post. So definitely different

Comment: _"Spam is any kind of unwanted, unsolicited digital communication that gets sent out in bulk"_ from a quick google search, it doesn't need to be intrusive